# XMLHttpRequest onreadystatechange called multiple times

Tags: php, ajax

I am implementing a login system in php and using ajax requests.

this is my request

```
hr.open("POST", url, true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

hr.onreadystatechange = function() {

    var return_data = hr.responseText;
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        alert('is logged');
    }else if (hr.status == 400){
        alert('is not logged');
    }
}


hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
```

but when i get the response back the browser launches various alerts. Can anyone help how to fix this?

Comment: *various alerts* - Could you be more descriptive?

Comment: it shows both alert messages more than once. basicaly each time i call the php file to log in the user or i log him in or i log him out. its like the page is called multiple times

Comment: i was checking and it displays those messages multiple times because it makes the post more than once. but i dont know why.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yeah its working as it should.......**onreadystatechange** may be called several times in one request..
And for alerting both the conditions is that whenever the request is okay that is **200**.

It alerts :

> 'its not logged'

and when it got **readystate=4** as well as `Ok signal` it alerts:

> logged in.

Then

**readyState =4** --> request finished and response is ready

**status= 200** --> it means the request is successfully handled by the Server.

So, 2nd alert popup because at least your request was successfully handled.
For more info:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http_response.asp
Here it is:

```
     xhrobj.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
      if (xhrobj.readyState == 4 && xhrobj.status == 200)
      {
        if (xhrobj.responseText)
         {
                //put your code here 
           document.write(xhrobj.responseText);
          }
       }
     };
```

Comment: i didnt know that.... but still i have the verification to readyState and status and it should occur only once (readyState == 4 && status == 200 ) right?

Comment: @TaLhaKhan thank you i had a similar issue i wasnt sure of after reading you answer i am able to understand it. My problem. Multiple requests are generated on click of a button.